# __NSCFString in NSMutableArray becomes nil outside of function where it is assigned

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, nsstring

I have a class in my app which represents a user, `OtherUser`. This class contains several `NSString *` properties. When I assign these properties with static `@"string"` strings, the properties are saved as `__NSCFConstantString *` values. When I assign them with strings converted from JSON, they are saved as `__NSCFString *` values. I am saving a mutable array of mutable arrays of `OtherUser` objects. When I access the array outside of the function in which the values are assigned, only the `__NSCFConstantString *` values persist, while the `__NSCFString *` values all become nil. Is there a way to convert my NSCFString objects to NSCFConstantString objects, or some way to work around this limitation?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNUGd.png) is what the array looks like once its values have all been assigned in my ConnectionDidFinishLoading method. User Test Testman was created with downloaded JSON data, while user Rose Lalonde was created locally with `@"string"` values.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEy3O.png) is what the array looks like when I pull it up again in my `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Test Testman loses all his data except for his ID, while Rose Lalonde retains all of hers. (I apologize for linking the images instead of embedding - my rep isn't high enough to embed images yet).

Here is my connectionDidFinishLoading method, which is called first and creates the arrays:

```
//Called when the connection finishes loading all data
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Connection finished!");

    //Converts downloaded JSON data to an array
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData
                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                     error:&error];

    //Checks if the array was properly instantiated
    if (!arr) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", error);
    } else {
        //Initializes the arrays if they are not already initialized
        if (!_bestFriends) _bestFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if (!_onlineFriends) _onlineFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if (!_offlineFriends) _offlineFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        //Loops through each result dictionary and creates a friend object with its contents
        for(NSDictionary *item in arr) {
            OtherUser *friend = [[OtherUser alloc] init];
            friend.firstname = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"firstname"]];
            friend.lastname = (NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"lastname"];
            friend.username = (NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"username"];
            friend.userID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[(NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"userID"] intValue]];
            friend.isOnline = [(NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"isOnline"] boolValue];
            friend.isInSession = [(NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"isInSession"] boolValue];

            //Sorts the friend into online or offline
            if (friend.isOnline) {
                [_onlineFriends addObject:friend];
            } else {
                [_offlineFriends addObject:friend];
            }
        }

        //user object created with local data to test best friends array
        OtherUser *tempUser = [[OtherUser alloc] initWithFirstname:@"John"
                                                          Lastname:@"Egbert"
                                                          Username:@"ectobiologist"
                                                            UserID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]
                                                       OnlineState:YES
                                                      SessionState:NO];
        [_bestFriends addObject:tempUser];

        //User created with local data to compare to downloaded JSON users
        OtherUser *tempUser2 = [[OtherUser alloc] initWithFirstname:@"Rose"
                                                           Lastname:@"Lalonde"
                                                           Username:@"tentacletherapist"
                                                             UserID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15]
                                                        OnlineState:YES
                                                       SessionState:NO];
        [_onlineFriends addObject:tempUser2];
    }

    //Adds the arrays to the array array
    self.arrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_bestFriends, _onlineFriends, _offlineFriends, nil];

    //Resets the table data
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"reloading data...");
}
```

My CellForRowAtIndexPath method, which is next to be called and is where the array's data is wiped, looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Creating Cell...");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //Creates a user object from the proper index of the proper array (e.g. _onlineFriends[1])
    OtherUser *friend = [[_arrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure Cell
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    [label setText:[friend fullname]];

    NSLog(@"Cell created!");
    return cell;
}
```

And my FriendsTableViewController.h file, just in case:

```
@interface FriendsTableViewController : UITableViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate> {
    NSMutableData *_responseData;
    NSMutableArray *_onlineFriends;
    NSMutableArray *_bestFriends;
    NSMutableArray *_offlineFriends;
}

@property NSMutableArray *arrays;
```

**Edit:** The OtherUser files:

```
//OtherUser.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OtherUser : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSNumber *userID;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *firstname;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *lastname;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isOnline;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isInSession;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSNumber *sessionID;

- (id)initWithFirstname:(NSString *)firstName Lastname:(NSString *)lastName
               Username:(NSString *)userName UserID:(NSNumber *)uID
            OnlineState:(BOOL)online SessionState:(BOOL)inSession;
- (id) init;

- (NSString *) fullname;

//OtherUser.m

//Initializes an empty User object
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.userID = 0;
        self.username = @"";
        self.firstname = @"";
        self.lastname = @"";
        self.isOnline = NO;
        self.isInSession = NO;

        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (id)initWithFirstname:(NSString *)firstName Lastname:(NSString *)lastName
               Username:(NSString *)userName UserID:(NSNumber *)uID
            OnlineState:(BOOL)online SessionState:(BOOL)inSession {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.userID = uID;
        self.username = userName;
        self.firstname = firstName;
        self.lastname = lastName;
        self.isOnline = online;
        self.isInSession = inSession;

        NSLog(@"Friend %@ %@ created.", self.firstname, self.lastname);

        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)fullname {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstname, self.lastname];
}
```

Comment: Where is OtherUser.h/.m??

Comment: Added. I should have included it at first, apologies.

Comment: property (***weak***, nonatomic) - That explains it.

Comment: Yep, a weak reference is exactly that.

Comment: Wow I feel very very code smart now. Thanks, I was convinced I'd hit a more serious snag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared "firstname", "lastname" and other properties as *weak*:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *firstname;
```

which means that they do not retain the referenced object, and will be set to `nil`
if the referenced object is deallocated. This happens when the JSON array `arr` goes
out of scope. `NSString` literals are statically allocated and never deallocated,
that's why Rose Lalonde does no lose here properties.

You should declare the Objective-C properties as *strong*, or – in the case of strings – as *copy*:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *firstname;
// ...
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *sessionID;
```

---

Btw., all the type casts and the `stringWithString` call in

```
friend.firstname = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"firstname"]];
friend.lastname = (NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"lastname"];
// ...
```

are not necessary, you can write this simply as

```
friend.firstname = [item objectForKey:@"firstname"];
friend.lastname = [item objectForKey:@"lastname"];
```

or, using the (newer) subscripting notation:

```
friend.firstname = item[@"firstname"];
friend.lastname = item[@"lastname"];
```